# Android AutoCompleteTextView with custom Adapter

Tags: java, android, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I'm stuck in a very similar situation as this: [Android: Using item selected in AutoCompleteTextView to populate another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425334/android-using-item-selected-in-autocompletetextview-to-populate-another-field/51291626#51291626)

After hours of reading through so many posts & answers at SO I've managed to reach the point where the AutoCompleteTextView is populating list of customers (The custom object / POJO that I need) using custom XML layout but I'm getting this error which seems to be occurring due to indexing logic:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
>           at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
>           at irisdesigns.studio.jewellery.Model.CustomerAutoAdapter.getView(CustomerAutoAdapter.java:76)
>           at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2365)
>           at android.widget.DropDownListView.obtainView(DropDownListView.java:305)
>           at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1408)
>           at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.buildDropDown(ListPopupWindow.java:1257)
>           at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:613)
>           at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1217)
>           at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.updateDropDownForFilter(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1086)
>           at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onFilterComplete(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1068)
>           at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:285)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Can someone please help ?
**Adapter Code**:

```
public class CustomerAutoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable {

    private ArrayList<CustomerSuggestion> customerSuggestions, filteredList;


    public CustomerAutoAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CustomerSuggestion> customerSuggestions) {
        super(context, 0, customerSuggestions);
        this.customerSuggestions = customerSuggestions;
        this.filteredList = customerSuggestions;
    }



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CustomerSuggestion getItem(int position) {
        return customerSuggestions.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.litem_customer_autocomplete, parent, false);
        }
        CustomerSuggestion customerSuggestion = filteredList.get(position);
        if (customerSuggestion != null) {
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_cust_auto_name)).setText(customerSuggestion.getCustomer().getName());
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_cust_auto_ph)).setText(customerSuggestion.getCustomer().getPh1());
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_cust_auto_email)).setText(customerSuggestion.getCustomer().getEmail());
        }
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }


    // Custom Filter implementation for custom suggestions we provide.
    private Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
            return ((CustomerSuggestion) resultValue).getCustomer().getName();
        }


        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            if (constraint != null && constraint.length()>1) {
                ArrayList<CustomerSuggestion> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (CustomerSuggestion customerSuggestion : customerSuggestions)
                    if (customerSuggestion.getCustomer().getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))
                        filteredList.add(customerSuggestion);

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = filteredList;
                filterResults.count = filteredList.size();
                return filterResults;
            } else
                return new FilterResults();
        }


        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                filteredList = (ArrayList<CustomerSuggestion>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else
                filteredList = customerSuggestions;
        }
    };
}
```

**MainActivity Code:** Text Watched and setAdapter

```
final CustomerAutoAdapter customerAutoAdapter = new CustomerAutoAdapter(getApplicationContext(),customerSuggestions);
            et_customer_name.setAdapter(customerAutoAdapter);

            et_customer_name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // you can use runnable postDelayed like 500 ms to delay search text
                    cust_key = "";
                    if (userExists) {
                        et_phone1.setText("");
                        et_cc_phone1.setText("+91");
                        et_phone2.setText("");
                        et_cc_phone2.setText("");
                        et_email.setText("");
                        tv_btn_od_create_phone.setText("+ Phone");

                        et_phone1.setEnabled(true);
                        et_cc_phone1.setEnabled(true);
                        et_phone2.setEnabled(true);
                        et_cc_phone2.setEnabled(true);
                        et_email.setEnabled(true);
                        tv_btn_od_create_phone.setEnabled(true);

                        tv_btn_od_create_phone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        et_phone2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        et_cc_phone2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    userExists = false;
                    // customerAutoAdapter.filter(et_customer_name.getText().toString());
                }
            });
```

**AutoCompleteTextView setOnClickListener:**

```
et_customer_name.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                    cust_key = customerSuggestions.get(position).getCust_key();
                    autoFillData(position);
                    userExists = true;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this line 
`CustomerSuggestion customerSuggestion = filteredList.get(position);`
try to use the original list not the filtered one, like below.

```
CustomerSuggestion customerSuggestion = customerSuggestions.get(position);
```

After some search I believe that this happens because the main list of this kind of adapter is the original one not the filtered one, so get view method is called referring to the original list!

Comment: I guess it will work because I have faced this problem

Comment: Thanks @Giulio Pettenuzzo , this seems to have fixed it. I'll give it a thorough go once again though before confirming. However I still don't understand, why use/display the original list (customerSuggestions) instead of filteredList ? How will / is the adapter display the filtered result ?

Comment: @viditkothari I edit the answer to give you an explaination, remember to upvote and accept the answer in this way you will gain some points too

Comment: Hi @GiulioPettenuzzo Thanks for the update. As I said, this part of the code is now error free but its not filtering the results. Every time i start typing, the complete list pops up and I don't see filtered result? I think I need to understand how & when does the getfilter and other Filterable implementations work because with that understanding, I'll be able to fix my code. Do you have a resource / an article which shows something like flowchart or lifecycle of the adapter?